# Keep unique record in a query based on another field - Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, unique

I am trying to build a query based on another query which gives me a table with the following fields.

```
Customer, Date of Visit, Material, Serial No.
```

Each Customer has multiple identical entries for Material. For example, Customer A has entries in Material like 1,1,1 but with different Serial No. So, a complete entry for customer A would be,

```
A, 1/1/2016, 1, 123

A, 1/1/2016, 1, 125
```

I would like to build a query that returns only one entry for each customer in Material, equal to 1 or 2 and one entry equal to 3 or 4 and one entry equal to 4 or 5.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: Can you add more sample data, and also the expected result?

Comment: Could you add more data and the expected result as already asked by @jarlh